# Why we can not create our own batch interface?

Tags: batch

why we need to implement database.batchable interface,instead we can create our own interface and implement it.

why we can not do it,even we can make an interface in apex,so could be exact reason for implementing database.batchable interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the Salesforce framework that calls your batchable class. That framework is not under your direct control; it has to call a well-known interface, and the developers exposed `Database.Batchable` to establish the contract between their framework and your code.

Having said that, you can create your own interface (or even an abstract class!) that implements `Batchable` but exposes a more expressive interface for your business needs. One thing I can think of is having a public property where you set the SOQL for the records you want to work with. After all, many batch classes just call some sort of SOQL in their `start()` method. I have done something similar with the `InstallHandler` interface, which I don't find very helpful or expressive.

If you come up with a better interface for `Batchable`, perhaps you can share it with us?

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly make your own interface, but only the native [`Database.Batchable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm) will allow you to initial a batch Apex Job. This is the interface that Apex expects to interact with to run the batch job. Any other interface won't work, as it won't provide the required method signatures.